# How to go from Maine to Canada by bus without going though Boston?

Tags: canada, buses, maine

Any ideas on how to go from Maine to Canada by bus without going south through Boston?

Comment: Hm, you're right. It's the reverse direction, and the accepted answer isn't as good as the other answer, but close enough.

Comment: Where in Maine? If you're in York, going via Boston isn't a huuuuge detour; if you're in Houlton, it'd be crazy.

Comment: @DavidRicherby and where in Canada...

Comment: I actually voted to close as too broad, not as a duplicate.  If you specify your origin and destination a bit better, you might get a meaningful answer.  Being able to get to St. Stephen by bus probably won't help if you're trying to go to Montreal, for example.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy.

1. Greyhound bus from Bangor, ME to Houlton, ME.
2. Take a taxi (or walk, but it's about 26km) across the border to Woodstock, NB.
3. [Maritime Bus](http://maritimebus.com/locations/locations-new-brunswick/woodstock/?submit=view) from Woodstock, NB to many points in New Brunswick, Nova Scotia, Prince Edward Island and Quebec.

Comment: http://www.westbusservice.com/ will take you to Calais, 500m from the CBSA post on the other side of the bridge in St. Stephen.

Comment: @phoog Yes, but then you have a 100km to go before you get to any sort of bus service.

Comment: That's why I voted to close the question as "too broad."